# SQL Server delete on multiple foreign keyed tables - performance

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to remove old data from a SQL Server database, given a list of ID's, but I'm trying to figure out how to get it to run faster. Currently deleting a list of 250 ID's takes around 1 hour. These ID's are attached to our 'root' objects, example below. Each of these has foreign key constraints.

Products

```
|    productID    |    description    |    price    |
+-----------------+-------------------+-------------+
|       1         |       item 1      |    5.00     |
|       2         |       item 2      |    5.00     |
|       3         |       item 3      |    5.00     |
|      ...        |        ...        |    ...      |
```

Sales

```
|    saleID       |      productID    |
+-----------------+-------------------+
|       4         |          1        |
|       5         |          2        |
|       6         |          3        |
|      ...        |         ...       |
```

Taxes

```
|     taxID       |      saleID       |
+-----------------+-------------------+
|       7         |        4          |
|       8         |        5          |
|       9         |        6          |
|      ...        |       ...         |
```

Currently, we are just passing a list of product ID's and cascading through manually, such as

```
DECLARE @ProductIDsRemoval AS TABLE { id int }

INSERT INTO @ProductIDsRemoval VALUES (1)

DELETE t 
FROM dbo.Taxes t 
INNER JOIN dbo.Sales s ON (s.saleID = t.saleID)
INNER JOIN @ProductIDsRemoval p ON (s.productID = p.id)

DELETE s 
FROM dbo.Sales s 
INNER JOIN @ProductIDsRemoval p ON (s.productID = p.id)

DELETE p
FROM dbo.Products p
INNER JOIN @ProductIDsRemoval p2 ON (p.productID = p2.id)
```

This works fine, however my issue is that my table structure has ~70 tables and at least a couple thousand rows in each to remove, if not a couple million. Currently, my query takes anywhere from 1 to 6 hours to run, depending on the number of base ID's we're removing (my structure doesn't actually use Products/Taxes/Sales, but it's a decent analogy, and the number we're aiming to remove is ~750 base ids, which we are estimating 3-5 hours for runtime)

I've seen other Stack Overflow answers saying to drop all constraints, add the on-cascade delete, and then re-add the constraints, but this also is taking quite a long time, as I would need to 1. Drop constraints. 2. Rebuild with on-cascade. 3. run my query. 4 drop constraints. 5 re-add without on-cascade.

I've also been looking at possibly just selecting everything I need into temp tables, truncating all of the other tables, and then re-inserting all of my values back and re-setting the indexes based on the last item I added, but again I would need to edit all foreign keys, which I would prefer to not do.

Comment: 1) Try to exchange @Temp with #temp (temp table). It should get a slight better cardinality estimate 2) Please post your indexes

Comment: Without the actual table definitions and what you are trying to delete the best anybody can do is blindly guess at what might be the performance problem.

Comment: You will probably need to evaluate each of your deletes in sql profiler.  Running individual deletes without the Cascade trigger should be extremely fast.  I would venture a guess that you do not have good index coverage for this particular task.  Start by converting all of your Deletes to Selects with the same Join and Where criteria and looking at your query plans.  This may end up painfully slow for right now, but once you hammer it out, you'll save lots of time performing this task in the future.